# Why when i click a <a> with pure javascript, "this" returns a url and the array returns "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, events, for-loop, onclick, href

I am not using libraries like Jquery. This is what i have:

HTML:

```
<a href="#aid" class="nav-link"> A link </a>
<a href="#anotherid" class="nav-link"> Another link </a>
<a href="#oneidmore" class="nav-link"> One more link </a>
```

Javascript:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function(){
        alert(this); // Returns a url
        alert(links[i]); // Returns "undefined"
    };
};
```

What i am looking for, is get the respective element that i am clicking. And then, get the href attributte (just the ID that contains), etc.

What i am doing wrong?

PS: Sorry if the title is poor

**EDIT:**

I made a JSfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2DRrJ/

Comment: `this` doesnt return a ur. it returns the element. use console.log instead of alert. If you want to use `i` use a closure since your `i` has expired (value = links.length) by the time callback is invoked. Just do `this.getAttribute("href")`

Comment: the toString() of <A> tags is the url in some browsers. your for loop has no scope.

Comment: The way you attach events to elements using `for` will give you errors. Don't do that.

Comment: As someone else mentioned, this is a common trouble that stems from how JavaScript scopes closure variables. This tweak to your JSFiddle is one way that you could isolate `i` so that it will be what you expect when the event handler is triggered later: http://jsfiddle.net/2DRrJ/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is the `<a>` element as you expected, the URL is its `.toString()` value.

As for the `undefined` `link[i]`, it's because the `i` variable is equal to `links.length` at the end of the loop's execution and `links[links.length]` is indeed `undefined`. This is a result of how scoping (and [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)) works in JavaScript.

Comment: @hicurin - The last `i` will be equal to `links.length` because of `i++`.